# server-side sql vs client-side sql

Tags: sql

I have been looking to find answers to this question from past two hours. I haven't found even one single relevant post/book/answer. Could somebody explain the difference between server-side scripting and client-side scripting to me. I know that triggers are part of server-side scripting but really, whats the difference between the two. Could you please provide me with couple examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about SQL or scripting?  If you mean SQL, what are you thinking for client-side SQL, [`Web Database`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).  According to that, it's currently frozen.

Comment: sorry, i mean SQL. i am not sure if i get your answer though.

Comment: You can have client side SQL scripts, I have done so in my Coils framework. https://github.com/zubairq/coils

Answer (score 4):

This could actually mean a couple of different things, but the explanation that is probably most relevant to you (based on your mention of triggers) is that server-side scripting is SQL that is precompiled and stored in the database in the form of triggers, functions, stored procedures, views, etc while client-side SQL (also known as dynamic SQL) is SQL that is contained within the application.

Some of the reasons for implementing server-side SQL include performance (the database can precompile and optimize the SQL), security, and maintenance (it is much easier to modify a stored procedure than to recompile and re-release your application).

The primary reason that we have found for implementing dynamic SQL is to handle situations in which are not easily handled through server-side SQL, usually involving variable-length where statements.

Comment: so writing a PL/SQL stored procedure is server-side sql? is that always true?

Comment: Assuming that the stored procedure is not dynamically created in client code each time it is executed, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can say there is really such thing as "client-side SQL".  There might be SQL commands/statements generated by a client application, but they are executed directly on the Database Enginer to persist and be logged.

In other words a client application might issue this:

```
select *
from SomeTable
```

If it is successful, that `SELECT` will be executed *on* the database server, not the client application even though that's where it was generated.

Now you might be trying to distinguish where SQL code is generated.  A client application might generate the bulk of the Data Manipulation Language (DML) code (i.e. `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`) and be performing OLAP (`SELECT`).  The server will generate the SQL and events for things like triggers.  The database engine, with a trigger, will see that an action was taken on a database, object, or the server itself and then this event will "trigger" the database engine to execute another piece of SQL code.  That would be server-generate SQL.

I think I understand your question, but please let me know if there is something else or I didn't answer it correctly.

Comment: yes,  that clearly explains my question. what are some other examples of server-side sql?

Comment: Actually you can have client side scripting, I have implemented it in my Coils framework  - https://github.com/zubairq/coils